# fpc Pascal Runtime error 216 before execution ends

Tags: runtime-error, pascal, freepascal

I was implementing adjacency list in Pascal (by first reading edge end points, and then using dynamic arrays to assign required amount of memory to edgelist of each node). The program executes fine, gives correct outputs but gives runtime error 216 just before exiting.
The code is :

```
type aptr = array of longint;
var edgebuf:array[1..200000,1..2] of longint;
    ptrs:array[1..100000] of longint;
    i,j,n,m:longint;
    elist:array[1..100000] of aptr;

{main}
begin
    readln(n,m);
    fillchar(ptrs,sizeof(ptrs),#0);
    for i:=1 to m do begin
    readln(edgebuf[i][1],edgebuf[i][2]);
    inc(ptrs[edgebuf[i][1]]);
    end;
    for i:=1 to n do begin
    setlength(elist[i],ptrs[i]);
    end;
    fillchar(ptrs,sizeof(ptrs),#0);

    for i:=1 to m do begin
    inc(ptrs[edgebuf[i][1]]);
    elist[edgebuf[i][1]][ptrs[edgebuf[i][1]]]:=edgebuf[i][2];
    end;

    for i:=1 to n do begin
    writeln(i,' begins');
    for j:=1 to ptrs[i] do begin
        write(j,' ',elist[i][j],' ');
    end;
    writeln();
    writeln(i,' ends');
    end;
    writeln('bye');
end.
```

When run on file

```
4 5
1 2
3 2
4 3
2 1
2 3
```

gives output:

```
1 begins
1 2 
1 ends
2 begins
1 1 2 3 
2 ends
3 begins
1 2 
3 ends
4 begins
1 3 
4 ends
bye
Runtime error 216 at $0000000000416644
  $0000000000416644
  $00000000004138FB
  $0000000000413740
  $0000000000400645
  $00000000004145D2
  $0000000000400180
```

Once the program says "bye", what is the program executing that is giving runtime error 216?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTE 216 is in general fatal exceptions.  GPF/SIGSEGV and in some cases SIGILL/SIGBUS, and that probably means that your program corrupts memory somewhere.

Compile with runtime checks on might help you find errors (Free Pascal : -Criot )

Comment: Compiled with -Criot -gl, and that gives error
`Runtime error 201` at `line 22`, which is `elist[edgebuf[i][1]][ptrs[edgebuf[i][1]]]:=edgebuf[i][2];`
  
Found it! http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/setlength.html says that SetLength(Len) allots array of length Len, and the elements are numbered from index 0, so the count runs from 0 to Len-1. I was accessing 1 to Len. So `setlength(elist[i],1+ptrs[i]);` worked!